How Can I Fix the Column Spacing in My LaTeX CV Template?
I’m working on a CV template in LaTeX, which I’ve provided below. Despite my efforts, I can’t get the right column to come closer to the left one without noticeable gaps.
Basically, my goal is for the margins of the page and between the two columns to be kind of identical, with the two columns differentiated by the background color I set for the left column. I achieve this separately using the 'TikZ' package since I want the color to cover the entire page height. The reason I used 'minipages' is to adjust the sizes of the columns as I like, since I want the left one to be much smaller than the right.
I’m not sure why I can't find a way to make it look proper. I cannot yet attach a pic, but the compiler shows the result I’m describing. If anyone has suggestions on how to fix it, I’d really appreciate your help!
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=0.4in}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Define light blue color
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{173, 216, 230}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{}{-0.5em}{}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill[lightblue] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north west)+(0.4\textwidth,-\paperheight)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\setlength\columnsep{0cm}

\begin{minipage}{5cm}
    \section*{Contact}

    \vspace{1cm}

    \section*{Soft Skills}
    blah blah blah

    \vspace{0.5cm}

    \section*{Technical Skills}
    LaTeX \\
    Java \\
    Python \\
    C++

    \vspace{0.5cm}

    \section*{Languages}
    Language 1 \\
    Language 2
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}

    \section*{Volunteering}
    \textbf{Role} \\
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{minipage}
\columnbreak

\begin{minipage}{9cm}
\textbf{\Huge Name Placeholder} \\
\smallskip
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\vspace{0.5cm}

\section*{Experience}
\textbf{Job Title} $\cdot$ Company Name \\
Date Range $\cdot$ Location \\
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textbf{Another Job Title} $\cdot$ Another Company Name \\
Another Date Range $\cdot$ Another Location \\
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textbf{Intern Title} $\cdot$ Internship Company Name \\
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 

\vspace{0.5cm}

\section*{Education}

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 

\vspace{0.5cm}

\section*{Awards}
\textbf{Award Name} \\
Brief description of the award.

\vspace{0.5cm}
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}


Like this?
I use 3 lengths:

for the margins  \mymargin initialized to 0.4in
for the width of the first column \mytextwidth initialized to 5cm
for the width of the second column (it will be empty) \mygapcol initialized to 0.8in

With the paracol package, I create 3 columns:

the firts width \mymargin \switchcolumn[0]

the second column will be empty width \mygapcol

the 3rd occupies the remaining width \switchcolumn[2]
\setcolumnwidth{\mytextwidth,\mygapcol}


I also put \columnsep=0pt
for the background color, I use a rectangle of width \mymargin+\mytextwidth+0.5\mygapcol in shipout/background
The Code
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/727106/how-can-i-fix-the-column-spacing-in-my-latex-cv-template
\newlength{\mymargin}
\newlength{\mytextwidth}
\newlength{\mygapcol}
%
\setlength{\mymargin}{0.4in}
\setlength{\mytextwidth}{5cm}
\setlength{\mygapcol}{0.8in}
\usepackage[
  % showframe,
  a4paper, margin=\mymargin]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{paracol}

% Define light blue color
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{173, 216, 230}
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}
{\put(0,-\paperheight)
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}   
      \fill[lightblue] (0,0) rectangle (\mymargin+\mytextwidth+0.5\mygapcol,\paperheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\setcolumnwidth{\mytextwidth,\mygapcol}
\columnsep=0pt
\begin{paracol}{3}

  \switchcolumn[0]
  \section*{Contact}

  \vspace{1cm}

  \section*{Soft Skills}
  blah blah blah

  \vspace{0.5cm}

  \section*{Technical Skills}
  LaTeX \\
  Java \\
  Python \\
  C++

  \vspace{0.5cm}

  \section*{Languages}
  Language 1 \\
  Language 2
  
  \vspace{0.5cm}

  \section*{Volunteering}
  \textbf{Role} \\
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
  \switchcolumn[2]
  \textbf{\Huge Name Placeholder} \\
\smallskip
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\vspace{0.5cm}

\section*{Experience}
\textbf{Job Title} $\cdot$ Company Name \\
Date Range $\cdot$ Location \\
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textbf{Another Job Title} $\cdot$ Another Company Name \\
Another Date Range $\cdot$ Another Location \\
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textbf{Intern Title} $\cdot$ Internship Company Name 

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 

\vspace{0.5cm}

\section*{Education}

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 

\vspace{0.5cm}

\section*{Awards}
\textbf{Award Name}

Brief description of the award.

\end{paracol}
\end{document}



Thank you so much! I later found out that using \begin{textblock*} and specifically \begin{textblock*}{11cm}(7cm,0cm) for the second column also worked.
